# Неизвестный идентификатор переменной

Tags: delphi

При компиляции пишет,что переменная img не найдена (она есть).
Это из-за кода выше команды

`img:= timage.Create(Form4);`

Если убрат ьвсё,что выше этой команды - всё работает. В чём проблема?

Вот мой код (не пугайтесь большого количества операторов if):

```
procedure TForm4.kaban4Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  timer10.Enabled:=true;
    k4:= image1.Top - kaban4.Top;
if k4 > 0 then
begin
if k4>= 200 then
begin
kaban4.Picture.LoadFromFile('sprite\gun3.png');
fire:=3;
end;
end
else
begin
 k4:= kaban4.Top - image1.Top;
if kaban4.Top> 200 then
begin
 image1.Picture.LoadFromFile('sprite\gun2.png');
 fire:=2;
end;
end;
if (kaban4.Top > 150) and (kaban4.Top < 430) then
fire:=1;
end;
img:= timage.Create(Form4);
img.Parent:=Form4;
img.Left:=kaban4.Left;
img.Top:=kaban4.Top + 120;
img.Width:=278;
img.Height:=68;
img.Picture.LoadFromFile('sprite\kaban\dead.png');
  img.SendToBack;
kaban4.Visible:=false;
mm41.Enabled:=true;
a:=a+1;
label2.Caption:='Убито кабанов: ' +inttostr(a);
end;
```

Comment: Delphi не чувствителен к регистру.

Comment: @Nofate, js мозг мой съел =(

Тогда надо либо переменную в процедуре объявить, либо на форму положить компонент.

Comment: какую переменную?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Похоже, вот эта `end;` в конце лишняя:

```
if (kaban4.Top > 150) and (kaban4.Top < 430) then
fire:=1;
end;
```

или после `then` забыли `begin`.

Comment: спасибо, ты мой спаситель!

Comment: я такое наплёл,что потом сам разобраться не мог(

Да... сложно с нуля игровой движок писать)

Comment: Для исключения подобных ошибок, полезно научиться писать читабельный код, придерживаться стилей оформления, информативные имена переменных и т.д.